# How to literally translate the 由人类艺术家挥笔 in 志愿者普遍更喜欢的作品都是由人类艺术家挥笔完成的?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

也许有人认为，在这种情况下根本不可能分辨出来。然而在每一次测试中，志愿者普遍更喜欢的作品都是由人类艺术家挥笔完成的。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 18. How to literally translate this part: 由人类艺术家挥笔?

I have reached at this point:

志愿者(the volunteers)普遍(generally)更(more)喜欢(like)的作品(works of art)都是(are)由(by)人类(humans)艺术(art)家(family or home)挥(to direct)笔(classifier)完成(be completed)的

As you can see, I am very far from making it make sense.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

志愿者(the volunteers)

普遍(generally)

更(more)

喜欢的(like)

作品(artworks)

都是(are all)

由(by)人类(humans)

**艺术家** (**artist**)

**挥笔** (swing pen = **draw** or **write**)

完成(to completed)

的(an adjective marker that marks the phrase 由人类艺术家挥笔完成 as an adjectival phrase to describe "志愿者普遍更喜欢的**作品**"

> 志愿者普遍更喜欢的作品都是由人类艺术家挥笔完成的

> the volunteers generally like the artworks that are drawn by human artist by hands

- 艺术家 (artist) is a compound word noun. Similar to 書法家 (calligrapher), 畫家(painter), or 音樂家 (musician)
- 挥笔 (swing pen) is a common expression that means '**draw**' or '**write**'. Similar to 挥手 (swing hand) means "to wave"; 挥汗 (swing sweat) means "to sweat" or "to labor"; 挥淚(swing tears) means "to shed tears"

Answer (score 2):

志愿者(the volunteers)普遍(generally)更(more)喜欢(like)的作品(**the artworks**)都是(**were all**)由(by)人类(**human[adj]**)艺术家(**artists[noun]**)挥笔(**wield the brush**)完成(completed)的.

You can now rearrange the sentence to suit the usual way of expression of your language.

Answer (score 1):

it is tough to translate into English in a polite and elegant way. But let me have a try
志愿者普遍更喜欢的作品都是由人类艺术家挥笔完成的。
Volunteers generally prefer the works of art that human artists delineated.

Answer (score 0):

艺术家是一个词语，艺术+家，这里的“家”不是house、family的意思，而是“在专门领域拥有很高的能力的人”，是人，不是house。艺术家可以简单理解为 在艺术领域有很高能力的人。

Answer (score 0):

They are talking about works of art done by people as opposed to computers?

也许有人认为，
Perhaps there are those who believe,
在这种情况下根本不可能分辨出来。
in this situation it is basically impossible to differentiate (between paintings??).
然而在每一次测试中，
However, in every test,
志愿者普遍更喜欢的作品都是由人类艺术家挥笔完成的。
the volunteers generally preferred the works of art done by people.